# History of functions of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have read that Jordan first defined the concept of variation and studied functions of bounded variation, in his 1881 publication *Sur la Serie de Fourier*, as referenced here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Jordan

Can anyone say what caused Jordan to create and investigate this concept?  Of course it must have come to him while thinking about Fourier series, but is there a particular Fourier series (or class of Fourier series, or functions, or any other specific objects of interest) that might have inspired this definition?  Is there some object which, because of this definition and analysis, he was then able to understand better?

(I haven't found a translation of this article into English, so I'm not sure if it already contains the answer to the question.)

Comment: Jordan was motivated by a result of Dirichlet that proved Fourier's 1808 conjecture rather than a specific series, see intro to [Reinwand's dissertation](https://opus.bibliothek.uni-wuerzburg.de/files/23515/Dissertation_SimonReinwand.pdf):"*He extended a result about the pointwise convergence of Fourier series of periodic and piecewise monotone functions proven around 50 years earlier by Dirichlet... This is nowadays known as the [Dirichlet-Jordan Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%E2%80%93Jordan_test).*" Considering differences of monotone functions was a natural step.